# Interpretation of cosmological redshift

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, redshift

I was trying to understand why we cannot explain the observed redshift of distant galaxies using special relativity and I came upon [this article](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2004PASA...21...97D) by Davis and Lineweaver.

Unfortunately when I arrive at section 4.2, where the authors explain why we cannot use special relativity to explain the observed redshift, I get stuck. In particular I don't understand this sentence:

"We calculate D(z) special relativistically by assuming the velocity in $v = HD$ is related to redshift via Eq. 2, so...".

What bothers me is the assumption that velocity is related to distance linearly. I was thinking that in a special relativistic model the basic assumptions were:

1)Relativistic Doppler shift formula 
$$
1+z=\sqrt{\frac{1+v/c}{1-v/c}}
$$
2)Observed Hubble law
$$
z=\frac{H}{c} d
$$

Combining this two i get the following relation between velocity and distance
$$
\sqrt{\frac{1+v/c}{1-v/c}}-1=\frac{H}{c} d
$$ and not the one proposed in the article.

Comment: You need to clarify your question to indicate what it is about this paper you don't understand. It seems pretty clear to me that Davis & Lineweaver are showing that a particular model doesn't work. Neither does $z \propto d$, as the briefest of glances at the type Ia supernovae data shows.

Answer (score 4):

The Hubble parameter is *defined* to be $\dot{a}(t)/a(t)$, where $a$ is the scale factor of the universe. **If** you wished to have a model where redshifts were not due to expansion, but actually just due to things moving away from us (and this is what Davis & Lineweaver are doing in the section of paper you refer to), then you could assume that $H = v/d$ *is* an equivalent statement.

Then assuming that the redshift is *only* due to a velocity, then special relativity tells us that the redshift $z$ is given by
$$ (1 + z)^2 = \frac{1 + v/c}{1 - v/c}$$
which can be rearranged to give eqn 2 in the reference you quote.
$$ v = c \frac{(1+z)^2 -1}{(1+z)^2 +1}$$
Inserting $v=Hd$ gives 
$$ d = \frac{c}{H} \frac{(1+z)^2 -1}{(1+z)^2 +1}$$

The equation relating redshift and distance under the general relativistic universal expansion model is quite different to the relationship between redshift and distance in special relativity. The difference becomes apparent at high redshift, as explained in section 4.2 of the Davis & Lineweaver paper. Observations of course show that the relationship between distance and redshift is *not* the one derived above, which therefore favours the universal expansion interpretation of redshift.

You can of course always hypothesise some ad hoc relationship between $H$ and $d$ (or equivalently $H$ and $t$) to make a model to match the data. I think Davis & Lineweaver's aim was merely to show that the flattening of the $z$ vs $d$ relation cannot just be due to the non-linearity of the $z$ vs $v$ relationship in special relativity.

Comment: I'm not so sure that we can mesaure the relationship $v=H d$, in fact we can mesaure redshifts not velocities.

Comment: @Cervantes !! The *whole point* of the discussion in the article was to examine the hypothesis that the redshift *is* due to a velocity and that the velocity and redshift are related by the first equation above. In fact they are *not* related by that formula (see eqn.1 in the Lineweaver reference), which only approximately works at low redshift.

Comment: If I can try to put @Cervantes's objection in my own words, perhaps the extrapolation of $v = Hd$ from low to high (0.8 in fig. 5 of the paper) redshifts isn't what we should be comparing to. Instead, perhaps we should have used $z = Hd/c$ (which agrees with the data just as well at very low redshift) and extrapolated *this* to higher redshift in an SR way, then let the velocities we derive from redshift obey whatever monotonic-but-not-simple law they have to to make this work.

Comment: (Is this what the paper is doing with their "$v=cz$" line?) In either case I believe you'll still have the center of the universe problem, as you mention [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/186417).

Comment: @ChrisWhite I am merely interpreting what has been done by Lineweaver - not supporting or criticising it. What you suggest would have worked just as well I suppose. As Davis & Lineweaver say, you can always hypothesise that the Hubble parameter changes with time just so, to make it work.

Comment: @ChrisWhite I think Davis & Lineweaver chose to do it that way because it is completely obvious that $z=Hd/c$ fails to match the data. However if you adopt the model that $v=Hd$, you might think that the curvature in the data is just because of the SR corrections to the $v \simeq cz$ relation as the redshift increases (and of course it isn't).

Comment: But if the relation $v=Hd$ is correct outside the Hubble  sphere you would have a peculiar velocity greater than c

Comment: @ChrisWhite this is exactly what I was trying to say!

Comment: @Cervantes I can't argue with that, but that is the straw man model that Davis and Lineweaver consider. I'm afraid people are looking at my answer in isolation rather than looking at the context of the paper. Nobody, including Davis & Lineweaver, are saying that this is a valid model.

Comment: So the upshot is that we can alway construct a model, although unrealistic and unappealing, that explain cosmological redshift with the SR approach?

Comment: @Cervantes Yes. Redshift due to velocity and cosmological redshift are not distinguishable. But see here for a discussion of problems for anything but an expansion model. http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/186417

Comment: @Cervantes Another thing I just realised. If one adopted a $v=Hd$ model in flat space-time, the Hubble sphere would be at ~14 billion light years (for H=70 km/s per Mpc). Since we have not measured any source with such a distance, then that particular objection to the model is not really valid.

Comment: You are right we have not yet observed any source with such a distance but this doesn't mean that a model that adopt a $v=Hd$ relation in a SR approach hasn't an internal inconsistency.

Answer (score 2):

While $z=\frac{H}{c} d$ is more or less the relation that Hubble originally found, it doesn't hold out to arbitrarily large distances in FLRW cosmology. $v=HD$ does hold out to arbitrarily large distances, provided $v$ and $D$ are interpreted correctly as FLRW recessional velocity and FLRW spatial distance.

The real problem here is that the $v$ in $v=HD$ and the $v$ in $1+z=\sqrt{\frac{1+v/c}{1-v/c}}$ are not the same physical quantity. They shouldn't have used the same letter for them in a single paper, and they certainly shouldn't have punned on it by substituting one quantity into a formula that expects the other.

The $v$ in the special-relativistic formula is defined in terms of global inertial/Minkowski coordinates. In most FLRW cosmologies, you can't define global Minkowski coordinates because spacetime isn't flat, so you can't apply the special-relativistic formula because the $v$ in it is just meaningless.

However, in the zero-density ($\Omega=0$) limit of FLRW cosmology, spacetime is flat, you can define Minkowski coordinates on it, and the SR formula *does* work, out to arbitrary distances.

There are two zero-density FLRW cosmologies. One is boring: the scale factor $a$ is constant and $v_{\small\text{FLRW}} = v_{\small\text{SR}} = 0$ and both formulas give $z=0$. The other is much more interesting; it's called the [Milne model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milne_model) and it describes a linearly expanding universe. In this case it turns out that $$v_{\small\text{SR}} / c = \tanh (v_{\small\text{FLRW}} / c)$$ which means that $v_{\small\text{FLRW}}$ is in SR terms the [rapidity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidity). If you plug this into the SR redshift formula you get, after a bit of manipulation, $$1+z = \exp(v_{\small\text{FLRW}} / c).$$

Meanwhile, in FLRW coordinates we have $a(t) = \dot at$ (for some constant $\dot a$) and, for objects moving with the Hubble flow, $$v_{\small\text{FLRW}} = a'(t)x = \dot ax$$ $$1+z = a(t_r)/a(t_e) = t_r/t_e$$ $$x = \int_{t_e}^{t_r} \frac{c\,\mathrm dt}{a(t)} = \frac{c}{\dot a} \int_{t_e}^{t_r} \frac{\mathrm dt}{t}$$ (using e and r subscripts for emission and reception respectively), and the integral of $1/t$ is $\ln t$, so $1+z = \exp(v_{\small\text{FLRW}} / c)$ as before.

The results agree because there is only one kind of redshift in general relativity, and the special-relativistic and cosmological formulas are special cases of it. Since they're different special cases, usually at most one of them is applicable to any given problem. But in the overlap of their zones of applicability, they're different coordinate descriptions of the same phenomenon, so they must agree.

I like Davis and Lineweaver's paper a lot, but they didn't catch every misconception about cosmology, not even all of their own misconceptions, and when they talk about intrinsic expansion of space they're just spreading another misconception. In reality there's no difference in GR between the relative motion of galactic superclusters and any other relative motion.

Comment: Howdy. It seems to me, that we're on the same side of the fence. https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14478/

Comment: @Marcin In [the disputed question](/q/737485) it seems like you're plugging the redshift of the CMBR into the SR redshift formula. The SR formula isn't valid in that context. There is just one kind of redshift and the SR formula is a special case of it, but it's the special case where $Ω=0$, while in real cosmology (ΛCDM), $Ω=1$. Length contraction and time dilation also don't really make sense when spacetime isn't flat.

Comment: Can you explain how does $\Omega=1$ correspond to this plot in real cosmology? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansion_of_the_universe#/media/File:Evolution_of_the_universe.svg I totally reject your rejection of time dilation / length contraction in curved spacetime, because in the Planck scale spacetime is flat. That's the scale, on which I "measure" these properties in GR.

Comment: @Marcin That chart isn't well labeled. The red "acceleration" curve is the ΛCDM one and it also has $Ω=1$. In any case what matters is that $Ω$ is far from zero, not its exact value. The problem with t.d./l.c. is that (even in SR) you can get any value for them by picking a different local inertial frame. To get the "correct" value, you'd have to connect one of those local inertial frames to the motion of an object billions of (light) years away across curved spacetime, and that's the part that doesn't make sense.

Comment: What values would you assign to the other curves, to correct the plot? *across curved spacetime* - that bothers me a lot and i'd be thankful if you explain - isn't spacetime flat on large scales due to roughly uniform density of matter/energy, even if we consider the density of dark energy? Does this curvature somehow reveals itself during the expansion? I think of the expansion as of an infinite series of snapshots - static, comoving frames, and in each and every one of them i regard the spacetime as flat.

Comment: @Marcin See [this chart](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Friedmann_universes.svg) which is labeled with $Ω_M$ and $Ω_Λ$ separately. $Ω_Λ$ is zero where not specified, and $Ω \approx Ω_M+Ω_Λ$. Constant-$t$ spatial slices are flat in ΛCDM, but spacetime is not flat. See the first paragraph of [this answer](/a/666648). Comparing peculiar velocities at the same $t$ is possible, though not useful I think. But in your case you're comparing objects with a $Δt$ of >13 billion years, never mind the $Δx$.

Comment: Thank You for the plot, quite explanatory. We know that there is no space without time, but if the space is uniform, the rate of the flow of time needs to be uniform as well, because they are inseparable and totally dependent from each other. When I think of a frame or a slice, I think of both the space-scaling factor and the time-scaling factor. They are uniform across the whole frame. I'm not forgetting about the time. Yes, I'm comparing the emitted wavelength with the received wavelength, the difference in time doesn't bother me.

Comment: How would you call the velocity, that is currently given by the Hubble's Law?

Answer (score 1):

This is just the approximation that $\beta \equiv v/c \ll 1$.

Because, $\frac{1}{1-x} \approx 1 + x$

$$\left[ \frac{1+\beta}{1-\beta} \right]^{1/2} \approx \left[ (1 + \beta)^2 \right]^{1/2} = 1 + \beta$$

Thus, $\frac{v}{c} \approx \frac{H}{c}d$, and $$v \approx H\cdot d$$

Comment: But in the $\beta\ll 1$ limit the SR and GR approach shouldn't be equivalent?

Comment: @Cervantes why not?  If you look at Fig.2 --- you'll see that the lines converge --- both the SR and GR predictions.  The main reason (I think) for the difference between SR and GR predictions is due to acceleration being in the GR model.  Acceleration is only important on larger scales --- where the difference becomes more apparent.

Comment: What i mean is that if we can make the assumption $\beta\ll 1$ both SR and GR should give the same results but we are interested in regimes where SR and GR gives different results so we can understand which interpretation is the correct one.

Comment: @Cervantes First, it sounds like the question in your original post would be much better phrased as, "Why doesn't SR explain cosmological redshift".  Second, the approximation that $\beta \ll 1$ only amounts to a 10% deviation at $\beta \approx 0.5$ --- which is far from enough to explain the discrepancy.  I think you do bring up a good point, however, that a more rigorous demonstration would not have made this assumption.  That would be a pretty easy calculation for you to do...

Comment: I don't think it would be so easy. What I should is: 

1)Find a mathematical expression for the z-d relation observed even at hight redshift (cheating a little I could use the one given by GR but even in this case I still have some freedom in the choose of the cosmological model)

2)Find a v-d relation that explain this data (probably a very unlikely one)

3)Use this relation to repeat the calculation of Davis & Lineweaver