# Tired Light Frequency Damping

Tags: classical-mechanics, optics, energy, visible-light, cosmology

Could voters please give discussion please, please?Thanks

Anyway, I know it’s been discussed but I have not seen good answers as to why Doppler effect is a better idea than the photons frequency slowing down over time. 
  There are many examples of systems that slow down but no examples of systems that expand faster and faster forever and ever.

Photon damping can easily match observations. For example if photons had an internal damping affect of around 6.666% per 1 million years it would match the red shift we observe in the universe. In other words depending on how far they travel their frequencies will slow down at the same ratio proportionate to their frequencies.

A 500 nm wavelength photon actually has a frequency of around 600 trillion oscillations per second. After traveling 1 million years the frequency will have reduced by 6.666% or by 40 trillion oscillations per second.

The photon would now have a frequency of 560 trillion oscillations per second which equates to a wavelength somewhere around 536 nm.

After another million years of traveling the photons frequency will again be reduced by 6.66%, which is 560-37.3 equals 523 trillion oscillations per second. This equates to 573.6 nm wavelength.

So after 2 million years a photon’s frequency will have damped from 600 trillion oscillations down to 523 trillion. On the spectrum this would have red shifted from the original greenish color to yellow.

Every photon in the universe no matter how far away will fit to this formula to match what appears to be universal expansion.
Why is one hypothesis better than the other?

Comment: It doesn't conserve energy? $E=h\nu$

Comment: @JMLCarter thanks for not down voting  just because I asked the question but could you please explain a little bit more? Thank you

Comment: Photons energy is proportional to frequncy. if frequency were to reduce over time, the energy of the photons would reduce over time. However, this would be inconsistent with the very well established theory that energy is conserved over time.
Doppler shift also changes the energy of the photon, but due to the photon being observed from a different reference frame than it was emitted.

Comment: @JMLCarter A photons frequency dampening could be explained like many other oscillations dampening in nature. On the other hand how is an infinitely expanding faster and faster universe considered energy conservation?

Comment: Where does the energy removed by this damping go? 
There are unsolved problems in accepted physical theories, to name two Dark Matter and Dark Energy.

Comment: @JMLCarter photons are the fastest and smallest things that we know of in the universe. How can anyone claim they don’t have a resistance to their oscillation? Or that they don’t give off anything. Like i said we see many other examples in nature of slowing oscillations and frequencies but no examples of never ending, accelerating expansion and free energy.

Comment: Until there is evidence for something, why would you, objectively, jump to that conclusion? The typical motive is that the theorist has a bias to prooving the age of the universe is about 6000 years to support dearly held religous beliefs.

Comment: @JMLCarter that’s silly, I have no such motive or could care less about Religious points of view. Nor do I see why that would have anything to do with how long things have been going on. My intent is an alternate theory that can be explained in the physical ways we see everywhere else in nature as opposed to theory thats infinite and cannot be. Like I originally asked why is one theory better than the other?

Comment: Well watch out for that motive. Why do you have a preference for tired light? I don;t see a connection between doppler shift and a physical infinity.

Comment: @JMLCarter I don’t have a preference, I’m wondering why you prefer expansion when red shift can also be explained physically and mathematically with my formula.

Comment: The question is badly presented, and this is not a discussion website. The chatroom is a better place for that.

Comment: Well, maybe its true what they teach you, that The Tolman surface brightness test rules out the tired light explanation for the cosmological redshift.

Comment: @sammygerbil Thanks, maybe I will take it up in chat but why do you think the question is badly Presented? How would you improve on?

Comment: It is a single block of text. Divide into separated paragraphs, space it out more.

Comment: @sammygerbil thanks, I’m not sure what happened. When I typed it, it was divided into paragraphs. I will check next time. Thanks again

Comment: energy conservation is not a great argument on this subject, since in expanding cosmologies, energy is not a conserved quantity anyways

Comment: @BillAlsept Tired light theories generally assume the universe is static -- if it is expanding they're not needed.  I believe that static universes either require some serious modification to gravity (a cosmological constant *doesn't* yield a stable static solution), are empty, or must be infinite in spatial extent.  Static, spatially-infinite universes are also presumably temporally-infinite so so e firm of matter-creation is also needed as the universe is not full of dead stars. If your problem is that current theory is 'infinite' then tired light theories are much worse in this respect.

Comment: @tfb A tired light theory could work with or without a static universe and The cosmological constant could be maintained with a condensing universe model. As the universe condenses into matter the average density of space remains constant. Everywhere we observe we see matter accumulating. As for tired light, it is only an observation of distance and has nothing to do with infinities. Models can be theorized without resorting to infinities, unlike the never ending and accelerating expansion theory does.

Comment: @user107153 the expanding universe has dead iron stars at the end of its life… why is it a problem if a static universe also has this?

Comment: Everyone is stuck on the old version of tired light. My question involves the damping of the photons frequency. it has nothing to do with photons losing energy because they traveled through space and run into stuff. Imagine striking a tuning fork and throwing it in space. It will continue moving through space at a constant speed  but the vibration will slow and eventually stop

Answer (score 4):

Tired light as an explanation for Hubble redshift is possible in theory, but it's not borne out by observation. The following from Wikipedia illustrates the fundamental problems that tired light models have:

> In general, any "tired light" mechanism must solve some basic problems, in that the observed redshift must:
>
> - admit the same measurement in any wavelength-band
> - not exhibit blurring
> - follow the detailed Hubble relation observed with supernova data (see accelerating universe)
> - explain associated time dilation of cosmologically distant events.

Example of a test of point 4 of the above: in standard cosmology, a very faraway supernova would be receding quite quickly, at an appreciable fraction of the speed of light, and we would see it go "bang" more slowly. This should not happen if tired light is correct. Since we do observe time dilation in these supernovae, it's a strong sign that tired light is not viable.

Here're more sources if you are interested:

- ["Tired-Light" Hypothesis Gets Re-Tired](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2001/06/tired-light-hypothesis-gets-re-tired)
- [Can "tired light theory" explain the observed redshifts of galaxies?](http://curious.astro.cornell.edu/about-us/110-the-universe/cosmology-and-the-big-bang/alternate-theories/670-can-tired-light-theory-explain-the-observed-redshifts-of-galaxies-intermediate)
- [Errors in Tired Light Cosmology](http://www.astro.ucla.edu/~wright/tiredlit.htm)

Comment: Blondin's original time dilation paper, which the vast majority of such claims appear to be based on, has been found to have been quite erroneous, though. Not only have the majority of the high-z supernovae been delisted (no longer considered Ia), but Crawford demonstrates very convincingly here that actual Ia supernovae do not show time dilation at all (they have to be calibrated according to the model that they're supposed to prove to do so, which needless to say is assuming the conclusion, and not scientific) in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.11237.pdf