# Broadening of SNIa lightcurves

Tags: astrophysics, supernova

Is the observed delaying of photons emitted by SNIa best evidence that space is expanding or should this be explained otherwise and how?

Comment: Related, if not dupe of, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/154507/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/186405/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/113939/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/223610/25301, etc

Comment: It's not evidence "for" an expanding universe; it is evidence *against* tired light scenarios.

Comment: It's closest to https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/156618/tired-light-red-shift-hypothesis but not a duplicate. This asks for alternate explanations; but AFAIK there is no plausible alternate that also explains the CMB, primordial abundances etc.